# PHP can nest class in two files?

Tags: php, class

I know that php can't nest classes, but it seems that it can if the two classes are in two files:

MainClass.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

class mainclass
{
  private $var;
  public function __construct()
  {
    require_once ('subclass.php');
    $subinstant = new subclass();
  }
}
$maininstant = new mainclass();
```

And `subclass.php`

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
class subclass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->var="this-var\n";
    echo $this->var;
    $test="test in construct\n";
    echo $test;
    function testvar()
    {
      //$this->var = "this-var in fun\n";
      //echo $this->var;
      $funtest="test in fun\n";
      echo $funtest;
    }
    testvar();
  }
}
```

No errors output, and the result is as expected. I just don't understand the `require_once`, it seems that it will include the code in `subclass.php`, so what's the difference, compared to write it directly at the same position?

What's more, how can I access the variable `$var` in `testvar()`? (Use as many methods as you can think), thanks!

Comment: These are not nested classes. And the required/included files are parsed during runtime, when the `require` or `include` statement is reached. `require` is not copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` does not include the code from the other class right on the spot. The behavior of `require`, `require_once`, `include` and `include_once` is unique: it "leaves" the current object and "merges" the code from the requested file to the global scope.

This means, that what you perceive as this

```
class mainclass
{
  private $var;
  public function __construct()
  {
    require_once ('subclass.php');
    $subinstant = new subclass();
  }
}
```

the PHP interpreter actually sees this (when you create an instance of `mainclass`):

```
class mainclass
{
  private $var;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $subinstant = new subclass();
  }
}

class subclass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->var="this-var\n";
    echo $this->var;
    $test="test in construct\n";
    echo $test;
    function testvar()
    {
      //$this->var = "this-var in fun\n";
      //echo $this->var;
      $funtest="test in fun\n";
      echo $funtest;
    }
    testvar();
  }
}
$maininstant = new mainclass();
```

As @Federkun pointed in the comment to this post, it's actually written in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Comment: doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php -> "However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope."

Comment: @Federkun thanks, I couldn't recall if it's there, so I actually never searched in the docs.

Comment: One more thing needs to be mentioned here. If no instance of class `mainclass` is created, the required file is never loaded and the class `subclass` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can defined any number of classes in single file just you need to provide a different name since all are in same scope. you can access $var using using $this->var, but you can not access private variables of one class in another class or can not by using object also.
So in your code you can not access $var of